# Match exact number of pattern

Tags: regex, tcl

For example, I have the following string:

```
-----ABC-----
```

And use

```
regexp {^[\-]+.*[\-]+} $string
```

can match the above string. But if I want to match fixed number of `-`, e.g. 5 times, how to do that? I tried

```
regexp {^[\-]{5}.*[\-]{5}} $string
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can there be a `-` in the middle of the string you're matching? For example “`-----SAMPLE-TEXT-----`”?

Answer (score 2):

The `.*` part matches the `-` as well. I would change it to this:

```
^-{5}[^-]*-{5}$
```

`[^-]*` means "any character **except** a `-`. (you don't have to put the `-` in `[]` if it's the only allowed character)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by *does not work* you mean that it also matches something like so: `-----ABC--------------`, you could change this: `{^[\-]{5}.*[\-]{5}}` to this: `{^[\-]{5}[^-]*[\-]{5}$}`.

The main difference is that I am specifying that mid section, that is, the section which in your example contains `ABC` should *not* be made out of dashes, so it will match 5 dashes from the beginning of the string (`^[\-]{5}`), followed by 0 or more characters which are *not* dashes (`[^-]*`), followed by 5 more dashes and a string termination (`[\-]{5}$`).